# How to better use Logic Gates on Pivot Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, logic, query-performance

The goal is to query data with logic based on a pivot table. I am wanting to support 6 logic gates, `[AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOR, XNOR]`, so that when a user creates a custom filter they can provide the logic gate and the `tags.id` values to use in the logic.

Example data:

```
+----------+
| data     |
|----+-----+
| id | ... |
+----+-----+
| s  | ... |
| t  | ... |
| u  | ... |
| v  | ... |
| w  | ... |
| x  | ... |
| y  | ... |
| z  | ... |
+----+-----+

+---------+
| pivot   |
|----+----|
| c1 | c2 |
+----+----+
| t  | a  |
| t  | b  |
| t  | c  |
| u  | a  |
| u  | b  |
| v  | b  |
| v  | c  |
| w  | a  |
| w  | c  |
| x  | a  |
| y  | b  |
| z  | c  |
+----+----+

+----------+
| tags     |
+----+-----+
| id | ... |
+----+-----+
| a  | ... |
| b  | ... |
| c  | ... |
| d  | ... |
+----+-----+
```

Expected outputs:

- `AND(a, b, c)` = `[t]`
- `OR(a, b, c)` = `[t, u, v, w, x, y, z]`
- `XOR(a, b, c)` = `[u, v, w, x, y, z]`
- `NAND(a, b, c)` = `[s, u, v, w, x, y, z]`
- `NOR(a, b, c)` = `[s]`
- `XNOR(a, b, c)` = `[s, t]`

The query representations:

- `AND(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='a') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='b') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='c')`
- `OR(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))`
- `XOR(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')) AND !(id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='a') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='b') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='c'))`
- `NAND(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE !(id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='a') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='b') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='c'))`
- `NOR(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))`
- `XNOR(a, b, c)` = `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')) OR (id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='a') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='b') AND id IN (SELECT c1 FROM pivot WHERE c2='c'))`

data is currently ~30K rows and tags is ~1.5K rows. I am currently populating this pivot table with 100K rows to do some testing with the above queries. I feel like the multiple `IN()` statements will make this slow.

Can these queries be fine tuned with Views, Joins, or other MySQL operations?

Also if you have suggestions for a better way to structure this, I am all ears. I have previously tried to use JSON fields in data to avoid using a pivot table, but that turned out to be extremely slow.

**EDIT**: While the `OR(...)` and `NOR(...)` queries work really well (~80ms), the `AND(...)` query performs poorly (~1300ms). Looking at the `EXPLAIN` and trying to follow [MySQL subquery opimization suggestions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-subqueries.html) to generate a better single subquery using `DISTINCT ... INNER JOIN` actually made matters worse.

What I did stumble upon through testing is that I can do a faster intersection of multiple lists of ids in Node with lodash's `_.intersection(...)` than I can achieve in pure MySQL.

So instead of using subqueries to form the `AND(...)` logic, I am able to pull the separate sub queries from MySQL and then in the API itself, use lodash to perform intersection and then generate a single list to use in the final `IN(...)` statement to do final filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OR(a, b, c) = [t, u, v, w, x, y, z]

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c1)
    FROM pivot
    WHERE p2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

The rest are messier, so let me ask how many distinct c1's and c2's can exist.  If it is no more than 64, you can do Boolean arithmetic on bits in a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

See also the datatypes `ENUM` and `SET`.

If you have MySQL 8.0, Boolean operators work on `BLOB`, thereby going far past 64.

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, not a performance tool.

`IN(SELECT ...)` is often very inefficient; try to avoid it by either using `EXISTS( SELECT 1 ... )` or `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`).

> AND(a, b, c) = [t]

is can be achieved something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c1)
    FROM (
        SELECT c1
            FROM pivot
            WHERE c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
            GROUP BY c1
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 3   -- the number of items in a,b,c
         ) AS x ;
```

Note:

```
c2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

can be written thus:

```
FIND_IN_SET(c2, 'a,b,c')
```

which might it easier to turn your operators into Stored Routines.

Comment: To answer your question. It is possible to have data(tags), 30K(1.5K)=4.5M, distinct options. Though it will not be likely at all that we see that many. On average we are seeing 8 tags per data point with no hard set limit.

Comment: specifically I am using AWS RDS MySQL `8.0.17`. As far as using Boolean arithmetic that would entail having one row per data point and having a binary mapped tag number to represent 0 for not having tagged and 1 for having tag, and each binary digit to represent a specific tag. in short `7` would mean that the data point has tags `[1, 2, 3]`. Is that what you are suggesting. That is a brilliant answer to a complex problem. I will research the limit of the BLOB binary form.

Comment: @amaster - (Thanks for the edit.  I do make mistakes.)  Yes, Boolean arithmetic can be done in `BLOBs` like you described.  But this is new with 8.0, and I have not played with it yet.  I don'tknow, for example how you might set bits.  With BIGINT, the `<<` operator is very handy.  The obvious simulation is to do MOD and DIV 8 to set one of 8 bits in a particular byte.  (I have done that before 8.0.)